# Universal Approximation Theorem vs Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, approximation-theory, neural-networks

According to my understanding of the Universal Approximation Theorem (one of the mathematical foundations of neural networks) when applied to functions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ it says that any function $f(t)$ can be approximated as:

$$f(t) = \sum_j c_j\phi(a_jt+b_j) $$

where $\phi$ can be any non-polynomial function and $a_i$,$b_i$,$c_i$ are finite sequences of real numbers.

If we choice $\phi(t)=e^{it}$ we obtain:

$$f(t) = \sum_j c_je^{i\left(a_jt+b_j\right)} $$

Comparing with the inverse Fourier transform:

$$f(t) = \int F(w)e^{iwt}dw $$

both expressions agrees if:

$$ F(w) = \sum_j c_j e^{ib_j}\delta(a_j-w) $$

that means that any function has a discrete spectrum, something not true.

I do not know if my interpretation of the Universal Approximation Theorem is incorrect and/or these calculus contains an error.

Comment: "Approximated as"$\not=$"equal to"

Comment: @Bananach: thanks for you comment. Yes, if the sequence is finite, there are an epsilon difference that could produce a random noise in Fourier transform of infinitesimal power. In case of infinite sum, it is an strict equal.

Comment: So what's the problem/contradiction then?

Comment: I don't know much about the Universal Approximation Theorem. But this I know, you can only write the Fourier Series of a function if that function is periodic, and that expansion can be written in exponential. Also, when the function is periodic, the Fourier Transform will in fact be discrete. So maybe your interpretation of the Universal Approximation Theorem might be wrong, as I believe that the approximating function can't be quite so arbitrary.

Comment: I believe you might find this discussion interesting:https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/13317/where-can-i-find-the-proof-of-the-universal-approximation-theorem

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an argument which should make your arguments invalid.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem),
the universal approximation theorem says that $f$ can be approximated
(arbitrarily well) on every compact subset of $\Bbb R$.

This is **not** the same as $f(t) = \sum_j c_j\phi(a_jt+b_j) $
for all $t\in\Bbb R$!

In the case of $\phi(t)=e^{it}$, one can show that such an approximation
is possible on each closed interval
(using theory for Fourier Series), but in general,
one cannot make such a claim for all $t\in\Bbb R$ at once.